# consume ArcGIS Server REST services API into MapBox GL API

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, arcgis-server

Can I consume ArcGIS Server REST services API into MapBox GL API? Please can anyone tell me whether I can consume an ArcGIS Rest Service into MapBox GIS.
Thanks!!

Comment: I don't think you can access the ArcGIS REST API using MapBox GL API, but you can access services published to ArcGIS Server by using other protocols: WMS, WMTS, GeoJSON etc depending on your type of service. Are you asking about tile services or feature services or ... ?

Comment: Trying to access feature services...

Answer (score 5):

You can use GeoJSON as your go-between format for feature services.  ArcGIS Server supports GeoJSON [since version 10.4](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/10.4/get-started/windows/what-s-new-in-arcgis-for-server.htm) and MapBox GL API supports [reading GeoJSON](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-polygon/).

Here's a snippet:

```js
map.on('load', function () {
    // Add a layer showing the city parks
    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'parks-layer',
        'type': 'fill',
        'source': {
            'type': 'geojson',
            'data': 'https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/ArcGIS/rest/services/City_of_Redlands_Parks/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outSR=4326&f=pgeojson'
        },
        'paint': {
            'fill-color': 'rgba(200, 100, 240, 0.3)',
            'fill-outline-color': 'rgba(200, 100, 240, 1)'
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much.....If you don't mind, can you please share me one example program with above "function"....

Comment: @BjornSvensson can you help me with source type json?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Esri's [arcgis-to-geojson-utils](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-to-geojson-utils) to convert arcgis rest services featureset result to geojson format, which can be used with mapbox-gl.